# CS50 Plurality: what does the return 2 mean in the source code?

Tags: c, return, return-value, cs50

I only know and understand return 1 and 0. Why was return 2 used in below?

```
if (candidate_count > MAX)
{
    printf("Maximum number of candidates is %i\n", MAX);
    return 2;
}
```

In some cases, I also saw return -1. Can someone explain why was it used?

Comment: Without more context it's impossible to day. Maybe that's how the function is supposed to operate? A C function can return whatever it wants so long as it makes sense. Maybe `2` is a particular condition being met.

Comment: It returns the value `2` to the calling function.

Comment: As a minimum, you need to show the function declaration (the line that has the function name, return type, and the list of parameters).

Comment: Hi and thanks for all the input, it's actually inside MAIN and not inside a created function, sorry about that. I noticed that when the condition is not met, it just stops everything like what would happen when you use return 1. Prior to writing return 2, return 1 was already used in an earlier line. I wonder if it has anything to do with that.

Comment: `main` normally returns 0 to indicate success. Any other value indicates failure. The return value from `main` is only useful if some other program looks at it. For example, a bash script might look at the value. On the other hand, if you're running the program in a terminal window, the return value from `main` is not used.

Comment: Some programs use different exit status codes to indicate different conditions. For example, `grep` returns `0` when it' successfully matched lines, `1` to indicate that it didn't get any errors but it also didn't match any lines, and some other value to indicate that it got an error (e.g. the file doesn't exist).

Comment: I see and it's making sense now. From what I understand, any return value that is != 0, means program is not a success and therefore just returns the function back to the caller. Thanks guys